# Using in-house distribution for iOS testing / QA purpose

Tags: ios, app-store, in-house-distribution, firebase-app-distribution

I’m currently working in a large telecommunication holding. We are using multiple accounts with the Apple Developer Program for different companies in holding. This accounts have multiple applications.

We are facing now a challenge with our main IT provider, it’s has a huge testing team. In order to facilitate distribution of applications, we are thinking about enroll to Apple Enterprise Program. Using it for building “in-house distribution” for testing purpose, such as: develop, testing and QA environments. Also distributing this in-house builds over Firebase App Distribution improving the QA process.
We hope that this configuration will help to avoid Device ID configuration and reconfiguration (when new testers join us or company workers that need test the apps), and facilitate provisioning profiles maintenance.
For production, we need do as always, we use the classic distribution build for Testflight and App Store in all our currents apps.

This are my doubts about this approach:

- We can enroll in both Apple Enterprise Program and Apple Developer Program without problem? We will use same accounts?
- We should configure developers in both programs (developer certificates)? how about applications ids / bundles ids ?
- Distribution over Firebase App Distribution is secure enough to avoid undesirable installs? And it’s considered a valid distribution mechanism for Apple Enterprise Program enroll?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need a unique Apple ID to be the administrator for each developer account (so one for corporate program, one for enterprise) but developers can be members of both teams. You need to manage signing certificate distribution somehow. A bundle ID can only be assigned to one program so you would need different bundle ID for enterprise and release. Firebase is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you Paul, i'm wondering if we would have two account, we need to duplicate some things like aplication (one in developer account and other for enterprise). Also, we would have to check the Team configuration in Signing & Capabilities over Xcode, i don't know if we will have two Team or the same Team in both accounts.

Comment: Yes, you would have two teams, two different application profiles, different signing certificates and different bundle ids. I strongly suggest that you look at at CI/CD platform or system such as Fastlane or Azure Devops if you want to use this sort of approach.